# VBA Vlookup of range of dates in different sheets

Tags: date, vlookup

I have zero coding experience and am new to VBA, so I don’t even know basics, but giving it a shot. I have a Workbook, with multiple sheet in it. The one that I care about are 2 sheets called DG, and Asp. DG has a button that grabs raw data from a server and populates the sheets ( multiple date columns with data value in adjacent cells). Asp has a button that grabs data as well but on a 30-day avg so every day in a month (columns A in Asp). This is the same case with DG sheet, but DG has data from different dates in a month, because it is not a 30 day pull. So that sets an image for you, now what I want to do is create a button, with a code that can go through a date column in DG and match it with a date from asp date and if there is a match, then copy and paste the adjacent cells values in DG to asp.

This is what I have so far with searches on the internet, showing just a vlookup for a single columns I want filled out in Asp, but its not working

```js
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim results As Double
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("DG")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Asp")
lrow = Worksheets("Asp").Range("A5", ws2.Range("A5").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
For i = 5 To lrow
On Error Resume Next
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((ws2.Range("A5" & i)), (ws1.Range("A11:B200")), 2, True)
              ws2.Range("AG5").Value = result
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
       End If
       On Error GoTo 0

       
Next i
 
End Sub
```

DG [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrwfZ.jpg
 ASP [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTsl0.jpg

Comment: You will need two last rows to work a range on two sheets comparatively.  Vlookups wont always work the way you want, you may go for a find / match combo.  What you are trying to do gets done a lot, Matching a reference and capturing offset data from the match,.

Comment: so Do you think I should scrap this completely?

Comment: Scrap? No.  But I would change it up.  Will have to make a "dummy project" to simulate what you are doing to show you one approach.  I have tried Vlookup several times, I wind up scrapping it and going another direction.

Comment: I am trying to do a dummy project, with a sample data fro my worksheet. its just I have looked at vlookup only so far and I learned quite a bit about VBA from trying to do it through vlookup. I don't even know how match/find would work. thats why i was thinking i should scrap it

Comment: Do you have your dummy project working?  Here is the simplified explanation, you walk through your dates on the DG page (sounds like there are less of them) and compare them to a range on Asp using .find, based on what is returned you will know if there was no match or a match, if a match you can get the match.row and then copy your data from one cell location to another multiple times, until there are no more DG dates to search for?  Make sense?

Comment: i am just trying to copy using 2 columns from DG to Asp as a dummy project, but so to build my code, from what I gathered from your simplified explanation is 4 things, 1- code that loops through column A, 2- find code that is looking in a certain column in DG, and then 3 - match codes - and then copy code is this correct?

Comment: Posted a solution using Find/Match protocol, Attempted to keep the project framework that you described, I do not know what cols you are copying or where to, so that part is left fast and efficient at this time.  If the Solutions helps you, You accept it by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's Friday, Here you go, something to look at and study.
I am sorry I didn't use Vlookup, I have spent too much time chasing ghosts with that.
Perhaps others have had better success, I think what I don't like is Vlookup if it fails an exact match sometimes it chooses an adjacent row and throws everything into turmoil.

Here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lrow2 As Long
Dim lrow1 As Long
Dim firstDataRow As Double

Dim matchRange As Range
Dim matchRow As Long

Dim i As Long

'Set up your Worksheet variables
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DG")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Asp")

'You used A5 several times, so I will assume dates are in Col A and start at row 5
'Set your row with first data, maybe you need two, if they are the same on both sheets you don't
firstDataRow = 5

'find the last row on each sheet, using column A, the date col
lrow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lrow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'In your mind you now have two data ranges, one for each sheet, rows 5-last dat rows

'Pick one sheet, the one with less dates would be more efficient, you mention DG has less
'So this might be built backwards from what you are thinking, since we are iterating each row in the col
'You want to use the shrter call, IF you know its shorter (your comments)

'Loop through each row trying to find a match on your other sheet
For i = firstDataRow To lrow1

    If ws1.Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then 'Test for empty

        'Here is the premise of Find/Match over Vlookup
        Set matchRange = ws2.Range("A" & firstDataRow & ":A" & lrow2).Find(ws1.Cells(i, "A"))

        On Error Resume Next
        matchRow = matchRange.Row 'Returns row number or nothing

        If (Not matchRange Is Nothing) Then
            'we have a row number matched on Asp, for our search item on DG
            'perform the "Copy", this can be done differently but here I am going to introduce you to a way
            'that can later be used with offsets and col #s, so that you may skip columns, data is not always adjacent
            ws2.Cells(matchRow, "E") = ws1.Cells(i, "B")
            ws2.Cells(matchRow, "F") = ws1.Cells(i, "C")
            ws2.Cells(matchRow, "G") = ws1.Cells(i, "D")
        Else 'DO NOTHING
        End If
    Else 'DO NOTHING
    End If

Next i

MsgBox "Search and Copy is complete.", vbInformation, "Completed"

End Sub
```

There is so much more to talk about in even this simple project to make this more bullet proof.  But this is a good start for where you are at.

[image]

[image]

Cheers! Happy Coding! - WWC

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me. i have a few questions and I'll show a sample of the data. 1 question does the format of the data effect match code? because the date format is in the sheets are different. here is a snap shot of the dummy project im working with.

Comment: I posted a link on the post please see it at you convenience

Comment: You bet it does!  Are you trying to match the date and time or are you disregarding the time?  Yes to do this comparatively it may need truncation (of time) in the code as well as recognizing them as dates (or we arrange them to match formats in code).  Do the excel sheets need to retain those different date formats or can you change them to match as the code is entered, so it is a non-issue?  One way is a more of a pain than the other.

Comment: i am just trying to match dates and disregarding time. and I prefer not having the format changed, but if that is the only option in terms of ease then I don't mind having the date formats match each other. preferable I would like to change ASP date format to match DG.

Comment: So I did some research, and I figured out how to make it so date format change in Asp to make is similar to DG except DG will have time part in its format while Asp wouldn't. now I did look into match as well, so there is an optional argument. that says only look at part of the cell I'm hoping that should be good to. match just the dates and then copy that data over. do you think I'm on the right path?

Comment: I do, You can always make "temporary columns" on a "scratch sheet" to compare modified date/time without changing the actual data.  Basically you can add a worksheet, modify the dates however you would like (truncating time if you wish) and use 2 col comparison to find the row, then relate it back to your data sheets.   Make sense, if you need to do heavy formatting w/o fear of changing imported data, you make a temp copy and change away.